# Check whether a variable has a type at compile time?

Tags: typescript

For the purpose of unit testing a new library with complicated types, I want to be able to check whether a provided variable has a given type. This needs to happen at compile time, since the types are erased.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function hasType<T>(v: T): void{}
```

This is only half of the solution: it will compile if `v` is assignable to `T`, but it proves nothing about `T` being assignable to the actual type of `v`. (e.g. `hasType<string|bool>('somestring')` will pass.)

Comment: Wait, why don't you want `hasType<string|boolean>('somestring')` to pass?  What is the use case here? It's not like you can assign a value to `"somestring"`.

Comment: TS doesn't make it easy to do this (and I still don't understand the use case)... but does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8rBN) work for you?